# Cross-Domain Fonts not loading

Tags: wordpress, hover, cors, cross-domain, digital-ocean

I have a website set up on Digital Ocean at http://sugarcoated.co. The domain was bought through Hover.

The IP address for this site is `45.55.209.201`

When I load the IP address http://45.55.209.201 in the browser, all fonts load fine, but when I load http://sugarcoated.co, I get the CORS error message.

> Access to Font at
>   'http://45.55.209.201/wp-content/themes/sugarcoated/css/fonts/montserrat/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2'
>   from origin 'http://sugarcoated.co' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://sugarcoated.co' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I'm new to server configs and am not sure which setting I could have possibly missed.

In hover I have set up the domain like so:

[image]

In Digital Ocean, my DNS records are as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To browsers, `http://sugarcoated.co` and `http://45.55.209.201` are totally separate origins.

As explained at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy, the  same-origin policy browsers follow at the core of the web security model prevents requests for certain classes of resources cross-origin.

Fonts are one of the resource classes prevented by default from being requested cross-origin.

For browsers to permit font requests cross-origin, the server the fonts are coming from must send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header that allows it.

So for browsers to allow `http://sugarcoated.co` to use fonts from `http://45.55.209.201`, the response from `http://45.55.209.201/wp-content/themes/sugarcoated/css/fonts/…` must include either a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sugarcoated.co` response header to allow just `http://sugarcoated.co`  to use the fonts or else `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to allow any origin to use the fonts.

Either that or you just need to change `http://45.55.209.201` to `http://sugarcoated.co` throughout the source of your documents that need to fonts or else just use a relative URL like `/wp-content/themes/sugarcoated/css/fonts/montserrat/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2` rather than an absolute URL containing the hostname.

It doesn’t matter that underneath, `http://sugarcoated.co` and `http://45.55.209.201` are actually the same server. The browser has no way of knowing that. For browsers to consider them as the same origin, the host parts must exactly match, character-for-character.